# iconImages not working: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven, user-interface, ant

I'm making a pet project with **java GUI (netBeans)** and while I was using **ant, images worked properly.** But I changed to **maven** since I don't know how to do tests work in ant with NetBeans. And the issue that I've encountered now with Maven is that **image Icons** keep creating this **Exception.**
[Image of the Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X3Mt.png)

I have this autogenerated code that creates buttons, actionEvents, listeners etc.
[Image of autogenerated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCmQq.png)

As I said, everything worked in ant but in maven it doesn't anymore. I'm using NetBeans. INeither do I understand exactly what to do with pom.xml, nor I know if I should put icons in another folder instead of "E:[...]\LeagueOfPokemon\src\main\java\icons". **I don't mind ant or maven,** I just want something that allows me to make **tests and** shows **images**. If someone knows what should I do please tell me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, but please don't post images of code or exception messages **ever**! [Edit] your question, please, to include the full exception message and all code relevant to produce a [mcve]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer is that I can use Maven and keep my icons in
"E:...\LeagueOfPokemon\src\main\java\icons".
But I needed to insert into the pom.xml the following code:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```